# RMarkdown Blank New File?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

New to RMarkdown.....sorry.

Whenever I do File-> New File -> RMarkdown in RStudio, I get the example file with the cars data set. Is there anyway to simply get a blank .Rmd file to start work on?

thanks

Comment: You could create your own template.

Comment: Otherwise you can go to your RStudio folder and then `Resources/resources/templates` and edit the file `r_markdown_v2.Rmd`. This file contains the default content.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the default RMarkdown template by editing the file `r_markdown_v2.Rmd`. Under windows you can find it at:

```
PATHTORStudio/resources/templates/r_markdown_v2.Rmd
```

If you are on a Mac, go to the Applications folder, right click on RStudio and select *Show Package Contents*. Then follow the following path:

```
/Content/Resources/resources/templates/r_markdown_v2.Rmd
```